# Strange behavior with UITableViewController and tabbed navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an application in which the requirement is to have sections laid out in tabbed format. Under one of the tabs, there will be a table view that has a segue to a detail view. When I setup this transition outside of the tabbed navigation, it works. however, when I try to do this within the tabbed navigation, I get a runtime error and crash. Is there a known issue of trying to have a tableview with segues loaded by a tab?

Thanks! Viv

Comment: No, there is no issue like that. What is the runtime error you get? What is your controller structure?

Answer (score 0):

Following is simple example for How can you use `UITabBarController`

Firsts Create all object of `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` in `AppDelegate.h` file  and use following method of `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds ]];

    self.viewCon=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.navCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewCon];
    self.navCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.viewCon.title=@"First View";

    self.fView=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    self.FnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.fView];
    self.FnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    self.fView.title=@"Secound View";

    self.sView=[[SecoundViewController alloc] init];
    self.SnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.sView];
    self.SnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.sView.title=@"Third View";
    .
    .
    // create UIViewController and UINavigationController As you need 
    .
    .
    .
    UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Australia.gif"];
    self.tbItem1=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First Page" image:img1 tag:1];
    self.viewCon.tabBarItem=self.tbItem1;

    UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cameroon.gif"];
    self.tbItem2=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Secound Page" image:img2 tag:2];
    self.fView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem2;

    UIImage *img3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Canada.png"];
    self.tbItem3=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third Page" image:img3 tag:3];
    self.sView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem3;

    NSMutableArray *viewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewArr addObject:self.navCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.FnavCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.SnavCon];


    self.tbCon=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tbCon.viewControllers=viewArr;

    [self.window addSubview:tbCon.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have already successfully implemented a UITabViewController and it works for all of my views, including tableviews. So, here's the scenario: a user cicks on a tab and a view with a tableview opens. The user clicks on an item in the tableview and the page transitions to a detail view. This is the functionality that isn't working. As long as I don't have the trasition, all the tabs work fine. The transition to detail view causes the crash. The same functionality works when not part of a tabbed view